# VueJS render doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

At work we are working with VueJS and we want to render one element with the contents from a 2D array. This needs 2 for loops to iterate through which isn't possible with a template. We found out we can do this with the `render()` function.

Our code (but simplified a bit) is:

```
export default {
    name: 'od-table',
    data() {
        return {
            testData: []
        }
    },
    render() {
        console.log("render function")
    }
};
```

When we include this component in the project the render function doesn't get called. I can see the component has loaded because I can read the test-data. No logs or any other sign the `render` function has been called.

It could be it's an obvious mistake since we have never got this working before, but since this is something we have to use for this problem we would like to know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You should have a compilation error. `test-data` is an invalid property name. `testdata` or `testData` should work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZKKmQX

Comment: At the moment of asking the question i didnt have the code with me, so I did it from the top of my head. This isnt a problem in the real code.

Comment: Understood. Other than that, I don't see an issue in the code posted. You can see in the pen that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what was wrong, but deleting the component and copying the old code in the new files seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given it worked when you recreated your component file from scratch, the issue might have been that in your original file you had mistakenly left a  section. That's what happened to me. If your component comes with its own `<template>`, it will be used for rendering and your `render()` function will never get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you're using `render`? You might be looking for `mounted`.

Here is a complete list of lifecycle hooks for Vue.js 2.0. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: We would like to create a responsive table using css grid. This table has different order by functionalities which have to be updated on click. I assume `render` would take care of this on its own where with `mounted` you would have to do it manually.

Comment: I think you're confused about what aspects of rendering Vue takes care of. Vue creates and modifies DOM elements. You declare these DOM elements in your `<template>` tag. The `<script>` tag simply holds state and scripting elements for your app.

Comment: The data I have contains the content for the table. Since the data is a 2D array (rows with cells) while we don't have a row container (because we are using CSS grid). This means we would need to use 2 `v-for`s in one element. Since this isn't possible we would like to create the elements using Javascript. The data which has to be rendered can be changed dynamically (ajax requests) so it would have to be updated regularly as well. Are you saying the `render` function doesn't take care of rendering dynamically? If not it's not completely clear what you mean.

Comment: One reason to use `render` is to try and implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917632/284111)